# how to import data from a excel list into a loop for a api python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, data-import

I am connecting an API and everything is going fine, now I have one problem, I have a data excel list like this:

| Name | Secondname | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alex | test | 2020-02-03 |
| pieter | guy | 2020-04-04 |

in my script i have a variable called: name.

```
name = data.name   
secondname= data.secondname    
age = data.age
```

Now i want to make a script that takes everyloop 1 line of data.

so loop 1:

ALEX TEST 2020-02-03

loop 2:

PIETER GUY 2020-04-04

and stores it into the variable: name, second name, age so I can send it with my payload

can someone please help me, I tried pandas and just the CSV module but it's just not working?

current script:

```
import csv
with open('Map3.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
print(row['Name'])
```

error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/printtest.py", line 5, in print(row['Name;']) KeyError: 'Name;'

here is my excel with error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having in the code is that the the dictionaries keys are case sensitive. You're trying to access `row['NAME']` but the code is looking for `row['Name;']`. That's the reason you are having a `KeyError`. To access every column in the file, you have to use the same column name without the delimiter character.

Here is the code with the problem solved:

```
import csv

with open('Map3.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
       name = row['NAME']
       secondname = row['SECONDNAME']
       age = row['AGE']
```

Comment: My fault, but in my own excel the name is like: Name, Age, in my code i did the same but it still gives me the same error. i tried with ; behind the key and without. both giving the same errors

Comment: in the loop, try to print the keys and see the what are the. Add the following command: `print(row.keys())`

Comment: i did this, and it gave me the right names back but i just didnt work.

Comment: i will close this post, since im going to use phpmyadmin with mysql thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `pandas` but you have to install a module that will read excel files. If you are using only `.xls` extension, than you the module `xlrd` will be enough. But if you are using another extension, like `.xlsx`, you have to install `openpyxl`

Here is the code to read every data in the dataframe.

```
import pandas

filename = 'myfile.xlsx'
df = pandas.read_excel(filename)

for _, data in df.iterrows():
    name = data.NAME
    secondname = data.SECONDNAME
    age = data.AGE
    # your logic here
```

Comment: Thank you! i already tried pandas and xlrd both failed. But will send you my script when im back at work and going to take a look at openpyxl

Comment: import csv
with open('Map3.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
       print(row['Name;'])